# Firebase Auth Bulk Account Creation

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication

I have a requirement where I have to create user in bulk in Firebase. I am thinking of using *importUsers* method provided in the Admin SDK since Web SDK has limitation of 100 acc/IP/hour. The issue is, *importUsers* does not do duplicate checking. If I add the same email twice there will be 2 accounts with the same email in the Auth Table. Assuming I have array of 100 users in JSON format, would it be very slow to do a loop and call *getUserByEmail* to check the existence of each user email before calling *importUsers*? Or is there any proper way to achieve this?

Note that I am running the Admin SDK in cloud functions.

Thanks!

Comment: How many existing users do you have? Calling `getUserByEmail` for each user is too slow. Instead use [`listUsers`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/manage-users#list_all_users) to get all the users and construct a list of existing emails. You can lookup 1k users at a time.

Comment: @bojeil it is a multitenant system so the number of users may reach thousands. Plus since it is a multitenant, listUsers will also returns users outside of the calling tenant, which is not efficient.

Comment: if importUsers seems to be not suitable to do this, what is the proper way to do bulk user creation?

Comment: I assume by multi-tenant system, you have multiple projects created. Firebase Auth does not have optimized APIs to create users in bulk across multiple projects.

Comment: @bojeil no. it is just an admin panel kindof that has different users, different data. its all under a project. anyway I just settled with createUser() using Promise.all() untilI found a better way. Hopefully with max 100 users it wont affect the performance much,